# Applying a class to a table not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm not a CSS expert but I believe my code should work (?).

I can make my code work without applying any class, but sometimes I need to restrict some tables from inherit a class.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wazub79L/) working** without applying a class in the `<table>`.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L15v3kjf/) not working** while applying a class in the `<table>`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I gave two different links from JSFiddle and uploaded two different images with red circles..and you can't figure out what the problem is?

Comment: "you can't figure out what the problem is". It is not up to the ones who want to help you to figure out what the problem is. It is your duty as a question asker to state your problem as specific as possible.

Comment: Well, it seems you have no reason, since he deleted his comment. Besides I was perfectly clear of what the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@panther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595669/panther) already [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940732/1763929), you have a bed selector.

However, if you want to use that style for the `table` that has **only** `.responsiveTable` class, then you'll have to use this selector:

```
.responsiveTable,
.responsiveTable thead,
.responsiveTable tbody,
.responsiveTable tfoot,
.responsiveTable th,
.responsiveTable td,
.responsiveTable tr {
    display: block
}
```

Which looks quite nesty. So I'd recommend you use a *CSS preprocessor*, like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) where the selector would look like:

```
.responsiveTable{
    thead, tbody, tfoot, th, td, tr{
        display: block
    }
}
```

Which would generate the above selector.

Answer (score 1):

On the 3rd line there is bad selector. The correct one is

```
.responsiveTable, thead, tbody, tfoot, th, td, tr
```

Your didin't work because commas missing and `.responsiveTable table` doesn't exist. Just `table.responsiveTable`.

Answer (score 1):

in the not working one you forgot the commas int the css:

```
 .responsiveTable,table,thead,tbody,tfoot,th,td,tr {
        display: block
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, will accept the answer when Stackoverflow allows me.